# Flatten multindex columns into separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks similar to this:

```
Date  Close                  Open
      AAP    AWS    BGG  ... AAP    AWS    BGG   ...
2020  10     50     13   ... 100    500     13   ...
2021  11     41     7    ... 111    41      7    ...
2022  12     50     13   ... 122    50      13   ...
```

and want to turn it into

```
Date  Close  Open Index2
2020  10     100   AAP
2021  11     111   AAP
2022  12     122   AAP
2020  50     500   AWS    
...
```

How can I achieve it using pandas?

Comment: Does `Date` is the index of your dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set_index` and `stack` to get the expected dataframe:

```
>>> (df.set_index('Date').stack(level=1)
       .rename_axis(index=['Date', 'Ticker'])
       .reset_index())
   Date Ticker  Close  Open
0  2020    AAP     10   100
1  2020    AWS     50   500
2  2020    BGG     13    13
3  2021    AAP     11   111
4  2021    AWS     41    41
5  2021    BGG      7     7
6  2022    AAP     12   122
7  2022    AWS     50    50
8  2022    BGG     13    13
```

My input dataframe:

```
>>> df
   Date Close         Open         
          AAP AWS BGG  AAP  AWS BGG
0  2020    10  50  13  100  500  13
1  2021    11  41   7  111   41   7
2  2022    12  50  13  122   50  13
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.set_axis(df.columns.map('_'.join).str.rstrip('_'),axis=1), 
              ['Close', 'Open'], 'Date', 'Ticker', '_', '\\w+').reset_index()

   Date Ticker  Close  Open
0  2020    AAP     10   100
1  2021    AAP     11   111
2  2022    AAP     12   122
3  2020    AWS     50   500
4  2021    AWS     41    41
5  2022    AWS     50    50
6  2020    BGG     13    13
7  2021    BGG      7     7
8  2022    BGG     13    13
```